# Wordpress blog index formatting with php template

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs

I have someone who wants to put the template they have for some of their pages onto their blog index page. The template on the pages is written in php and I am not too familiar with php coding. The template is basically a custom sidebar that is editable in the widget area. It is already set up and being used on other pages but it needs to be integrated into the blog index page.

Here is the current blog index php code:

```
    <div id="primary">
        <div id="content" role="main">

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php twentyeleven_content_nav( 'nav-above' ); ?>

            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php twentyeleven_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

        <?php else : ?>

            <article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">
                <header class="entry-header">
                    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Nothing Found', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></h1>
                </header><!-- .entry-header -->

                <div class="entry-content">
                    <p><?php _e( 'Apologies, but no results were found for the requested archive. Perhaps searching will help find a related post.', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></p>
                    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                </div><!-- .entry-content -->
            </article><!-- #post-0 -->

        <?php endif; ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
```

And here is the template code:

```
    <div id="primary">

        <div id="content" role="main">
        <div id="featured-header"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full');?></div>
        <div class="left-content">
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>



                <?php if( is_front_page()){} else {?>
                    <div id="secondary" class="facility-widget-area" role="complementary">
                <?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-12' ) ) : ?>

                <?php
                    the_widget( 'Twenty_Eleven_Ephemera_Widget', '', array( 'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">', 'after_title' => '</h3>' ) );
                ?>

                <?php endif; // end sidebar widget area ?>

                        <?php the_secondary_content(); ?> <!-- sidebar lower content area -->
                    </div><!-- .widget-area -->
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <div class="right-contentchild">
                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                <header class="entry-header">
                <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                </header><!-- .entry-header -->

                <div class="entry-content">
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                    <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link"><span>' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyeleven' ) . '</span>', 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
                </div><!-- .entry-content -->
                <footer class="entry-meta">
                <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentyeleven' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
                </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
                </article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
            </div>


                <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
```

Is there any way to have the template coded into the index? Or do I have to go about this in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

If you replace:

```
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

with the equivalent part of the new template:

```
   <div id="featured-header"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full');?></div>
    <div class="left-content">
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        ...
       <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

then you will probably have what you are looking for.

Comment: In thinking about it, if I change index.php in wordpress, is that going to change anything else in the site? I dont see a blog.php so I assume that its going to be index.php.

Comment: index.php is used as a default for posts. If you want to keep your options open, you could make a choice: if (it's some particular types of posts) { show the other template } else { use the original code in index.php }. That would give you more fine-grained control.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your setup looks like, but WordPress Widgets allow you to show/hide sidebars on any page (which can be edited in the functions to give you full control, a little, or none at all if I'm not mistaken). If you go to `Appearance > Widgets` and look at `Sidebar Widget Area` you can expand each item and tell it which page to show on. If it doesn't show you right away, click the Visibility button and change your options. See the screenshot below for an example.

[image: Widgets Section of Admin Dashboard]

Comment: I dont see this ability in the theme. I have never seen that before in Wordpress.

Comment: Do you have the Jetpack plugin installed? If not, check out [this article](http://sangkrit.net/2013/09/how-to-enable-wordpress-widget-visibility-module-without-jetpack/) on how to enable widget visibility without it. If you do have it installed you can check out [this article](http://sangkrit.net/2013/08/30/powerful-wordpress-widget-visibility-feature-from-jetpack/)